# count equivalence relations on a set with 6 members including and excluding certain pairs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I want to count the equivalence relations on the set ${\{1,2,3,4,5,6}\}$ with the conditions that the relation includes the tuples ${(1,2)}$ and ${(2,3)}$ but it does not include the tuple ${(3,4)}$
I tried reducing the problem to this :

The relation should have the tuple ${(1,2)}$ and ${(2,1)}$ ( Mirror principle ), likewise with ${(3,2)}$ and ${(2,3)}$, and it should not include ${(4,3)}$ if it does not include ${(3,4)}$. It should also include ${(2,2)}$ and ${(3,3)}$ and other elements likewise.

Other similar questions were associated with bell number and bijections with set divisions , if we want to follow the similar solution how should our set be divided in order not to include or include the tuples provided?

Comment: In this case you want to divide your set so 3,4 are in different 'divisions' and 1,2,3 are in the same division

Comment: Before you commented I actually did what you said and figured out 10 divisions .if anyone else has some other answer please share it with me

Comment: The number of equivalence relations is equal to the number of set partitions.  Count set partitions which include the elements $1, 2, 3$ in one part and the element $4$ in another part.

Comment: To elaborate, we already know $1,2,3$ must be in one part and $4$ in another.  All that remains to be asked is whether $5$ was in the same part with $1,2,3$, or in the same part as $4$, or in a new part on its own.  Similarly $6$ is either in the same part as $1,2,3$ or in the same part as $4$, or in a part on its own.  Alternatively still, $5$ and $6$ could have been in their new parts together rather than separately.  This gives $3\cdot 3 + 1 = 10$ options.  I'm sure I've seen this exact question a year or two ago, but I'm not sure I'd be able to find it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I think this is the solution as we have reached the same result .Would you be kind enough to post it as an answer so we can close the question ?

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question, which will allow you to close it yourself (although, I believe you will have to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use the division association but we only form divisions that have 1 2 and 3  in the same set and exclude 4 from those .
counting the divisions we conclude that 10 ways are possible